# How to do a "search function " in react when using axios to call information from Json?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, search, filtering

I am comparatively new to react and is practising myself with various scenarios. I am trying to call data from a json file online using "Axios" and then use search to filter out the names.

But I am not able to move past except keeping the components. I did search online about keeping an search filter, but was unsuccessful in finding a simple/useful one for my scenario. A helping hand is always appreciated!

My apologies, if its a too simple question.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

class Activities extends Component {
    state = {
        users: []
    };

    async componentDidMount() {
        const { data: users } = await axios.get(
            "https://api.myjson.com/bins/1fj65g"
        );
        this.setState({ users });
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h3 style={{ textAlign: "center" }}> Activities</h3>
                <div>
                    {this.state.users.map(user => (
                        <ul key={user.id} class="list-group card card-1">
                            <li class="list-group-item">{user.sender.name}</li>
                        </ul>
                    ))}
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Activities;
```

This is my json file online. I am looking forward to search for the names. http://myjson.com/1fj65g

Comment: I don't see any attempt. Where is your search? I don't see any input, nor any attempt to actually filter the data based on the input.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

3 steps.

Add an text input node in your JSX and bind its `onChange` event to an event handler in your class and the `value` to the state value we will set :

```
<input type='text' onChange={this.searchChanged} value={this.state.search}/>
```

Create a handler to change your state when the `onChange` event is fired in your class :

```
searchChanged = event => {
    this.setState({ search: event.target.value })
}
```

And finally use [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) on your array and [`includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) to only keep the data corresponding to your filter :

```
{this.state.users
    .filter(user => user.name.includes(this.state.search))
    .map(user => (
        <ul key={user.id} class="list-group card card-1">
            <li class="list-group-item">{user.sender.name}</li>
        </ul>
    )
)}
```

Comment: Thank you for helping out Treycos! But i ran to a problem while running the code, is it possible for you to clarify that? It gives an error "TypeError: Cannot read property 'includes' of undefined". `Is it because its not binded properly?

Comment: The error is clear, this is because `user.name` is undefined. Change it to `user.receiver.name` or whatever value you want to filter

Comment: I did try that. I used "user.sender.name" and then a new error called "TypeError: user.sender.name.includes(...).map is not a function" came up and i was searching online for solutions

Comment: Whoops, I just noticed there was a missing parenthesis after the `includes` statement : `includes(this.state.search))`

Comment: Treycos! Thanks a lot. It really helped :)