# React "TypeError: product.name.includes(...).map is not a function" when attempting to filter through product list

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a React application that displays a list of products when getting product data from a database using an axios.get call. That part works perfectly, but today I've tried implementing a search feature to only display product names that matches the search query but when I attempt to type even a single letter the application crashes and I get this:

```
TypeError: product.name.includes(...).map is not a function

function productList() {
  40 |        if(searchTerm) {
> 41 |            return products.filter(product => product.name.includes(searchTerm).map(function(currentProduct, i) {
     | ^  42 |                return <Product product={currentProduct} key={i} />;
  43 |            }));
  44 |        } else {
```

How can I implement this correctly? I was trying to follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54523266/how-to-do-a-search-function-in-react-when-using-axios-to-call-information-fro) previously answered question as a guide.

productListPublic.js:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { CardColumns, Card, Row, Col, ListGroup, Form } from "react-bootstrap";
import axios from "axios";

function ProductListPublic(props) {
    const [isError, setIsError] = useState(false);
    const [products, setProducts] = useState([]);
    const [searchTerm, setSearchTerm] = useState("");

    const Product = props => (
        <Card>
            <Row>
                <Col md={{ span: 4 }}>
                    <Card.Title className="mt-4 text-center">
                        <Link to={`/products/list/${props.product._id}/`}>{props.product.name}</Link>
                    </Card.Title>
                </Col>
                <Col md={{ span: 8 }}>
                <ListGroup>
                    <ListGroup.Item className="text-truncate">{props.product.description}</ListGroup.Item>
                    <ListGroup.Item>{props.product.stock} in stock</ListGroup.Item>
                </ListGroup>
                </Col>
            </Row>
        </Card>
    )

    useEffect(() => {
        axios.get("http://localhost:4000/products/")
        .then(res => {
            setProducts(res.data);
        }).catch(function(err) {
            setIsError(true);
        })

    }, []);

    function productList() {
        if(searchTerm) {
            return products.filter(product => product.name.includes(searchTerm).map(function(currentProduct, i) {
                return <Product product={currentProduct} key={i} />;
            }));
        } else {
            return products.map(function(currentProduct, i) {
                return <Product product={currentProduct} key={i} />;
            })
        }
    }

    return (
        <div className="text-center">
            <Form>
                <Form.Row>
                    <Form.Group as={Col}>
                        <Form.Label htmlFor="formSearch">Search Products</Form.Label>
                        <Form.Control
                                    controlid="formSearch"
                                    type="text"
                                    value={searchTerm}
                                    onChange={e => {
                                        setSearchTerm(e.target.value);
                                    }}
                                    placeholder="Product Name"
                                    />
                    </Form.Group>
                </Form.Row>
            </Form>
            <h2>Products List</h2>
            <CardColumns>
                { productList() }
            </CardColumns>
            { isError &&<p>Something went wrong with getting the products!</p> }
        </div>
    )
}

export default ProductListPublic;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Close the `filter` parentheses then use `map` on the resultant list.

```
return products.filter(product => product.name.includes(searchTerm)).map((currentProduct, i) => {
    return <Product product={currentProduct} key={i} />;
});
```